# Can I store a Rails wordlist in database with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I created a Rails app, with some word lists that I would like to store in database. The wordlist is user-based and created dynamically, i.e. it will be changed according to user input. The app itself will read different lists all the time, as I use it as some sort of permission control. It seems that I can't simply put them in database as a string.

So here are some questions.

1. Can a wordlist-type variable store in database?
2. If I store a string work many words in database, can I read it and change it back to a wordlist?

Thank all~

Comment: What kind of data do these lists represent? What are they for? How often will they be accessed?

Comment: You can store words in the database as strings--you may need to provide more info.

Comment: What do you mean by wordlist? Array? Hash?

Comment: um... how about %w{apple banana melon pear}?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table in the DB....let's say named `words` with at least columns:

- **id**  `integer`
- **word** `varchar(50)`

then create an `ActiveRecord` model like:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord:Base
end
```

the use this model in your controller to find/create/modify/delete words from the DB

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a model, and you just want to store these words additionally, you can simply use `serialize :word_list` in your existing model. Where the `word_list` is a text column in your table. This way you can use this `word_list` in your rails app as an array.

Of course, it means it is not something large, and you dont want to use sql filters on it. It can be done, but a bit problematic. In that case, better to use another model, and store a `user_id` or something, to indicate connection. `rails g model word user_id:integer word:string` or something like this.